# How can I make a generic DynamoDBTypeConverter to convert a List of enums into a list of strings ? [DynamoDB]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, amazon-dynamodb

My question is how could I make a generic converter class that implements the DynamoDBTypeConverter. This class will need to work with any enum class I provide.

Here is where I provide a converter to the field:

```
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = TypeConverter.class)
private List<Types> types;
```

Here is the converter that I tried doing:

```
public class TypeConverter<T extends Enum<T> & OperationsEnums> implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<List<String>, List<T>> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    public TypeConverter(Class<T> typeClass){
        this.type = typeClass;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convert(List<T> object) {
        var result = new ArrayList<String>();
        object
                .forEach(value -> result.add(value.toString()));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> unconvert(List<String> objectsString) {
        var result = new ArrayList<T>();
        objectsString
                .forEach(value -> result.add(Enum.valueOf(type, value)));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can somebody share their knowledge on this problem, if they had a similar problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have generic converters because of the way the `@Convert` annotation works. You will need a subclass of your generic converter per enum that passes the enum class to the super constructor.

Comment: Got it thank you, and how can I do this in another way ?

Comment: There is no other way I think. You might be able to use Hibernate's UserType abstraction for this purpose, as I think you have access to the underlying type there, but not sure.